# Create rounded block without border-radius

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

I create my own website and I can't understand how correctly create rounded block (see red rectangle in the picture here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/43315655/planeto-template.jpg)

This block will be display at different screens (from 960 px to HD). I have tried to do with border-radius but it's wrong.

Please, help me with any links, advice or code examples :)

Comment: You should make an image in Photoshop or Gimp and use it.

Comment: csanonymous, that is just wrong. There are ways to do it with pure CSS. That way the page loads way faster.

Answer (score 2):

The image you posted is an HTML template. If they did it, don'T you think it is possible?

It is, just put a border on bottom left and bottom right. One value is 100% and the other is the height you want the curve to stop :

```
border-bottom-right-radius : 100% 100px;
border-bottom-left-radius : 100% 100px;
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/yqf9a/1/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you don't understand about border-radius, but the W3C Wiki explains the use of the border-radius property pretty good: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Also try the CSS Border Radius Generator: http://border-radius.com/

Comment: You shouldn't quote w3schools when talking about w3c standards:  http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: I think with border-radius property I can't create such block as you can see in the picture. I tried and it wasn't successfully.

Comment: The border radius generator does not provide the full potential of the border-radius property. You can supply different values for the width and the height of the 1/4th-circle: border-top-left-radius: 2em 0.5em; Try messing around with it a bit. or provide a link to the original page and i will look up how it was done there.